# How can I load Metadata.xml in Experience Optimization?

Tags: web8, experience-optimization

When I was installing SmartTarget 2014 SP1 I used to execute the next command for load the metadata.xml file.

```
bin/run-etl-job STjob.kjb "-DINSTANCE=indexer" "-DTRIGGER=load-data" "-DUNIVERSE=catalog01" "-DEXECUTIONPATH=/opt/fredhopper/data/instances/indexer/custom/"
```

But I can see in the documentation of installing Experience Optimization this step, only "copy STjob.kjb to fredhopper/data/instances/etl"

[SDL Documentation Center](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3D.kjb&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1460979425748&currentQuery=.kjb&currentScope=)

Does anyone if this command still being necessary? I tried to execute but I recieve an error.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you refer to **run.kjb** (default configuration of Fredhopper installation).
I read in SDL Documentation Center  in 
Kettle jobs section ([Experience OptimizationFredhopper extensions and configuration files](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-EC5C8E72-6B9F-4E14-B7A8-23195C6C4F75.xml&docid=GUID-EC5C8E72-6B9F-4E14-B7A8-23195C6C4F75&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EC5C8E72-6B9F-4E14-B7A8-23195C6C4F75))
You need to install the Kettle job file called **STJob.kjb**

About my issue the problem was an error with capital letter (I was installing in Linux). Now it's works fine.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

The command hasn't changed and was always optional. I guess that's why it wasn't included in the quick start guide.

It just loads in some dummy data and deletes it again, so that the Business Manager is available immediately (which can be handy to test that your installation works). Without it, you'll need to publish items first before the BM is available.

That said, it's listed as the last step in the '[Installing Experience Optimization on premise](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8)' section of the documentation.